# When i rotate an object on the x axis it rotates on the z axis too

Tags: error, axis

So, I've been working on this car model, but whenever I try to rotate the components of the tyres on the x axis it does a weird rotation that affects the other rotation axis.
I'm pretty sure it has something to do with me changing its original location and rotation but back then I made sure to apply them.
I've tried everything and nothing seems to work, I've applied the rotation, changed the transformation orientation, move the object origin and nothing has worked.
I´ll leave you the file here so you can see the problem better.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qh6kAuOq9LBmV1-uA-j6PL5EgJJkI0FD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello please show a screenshot or share your object (not your whole file but just the tyre)

Comment: As you suspect it's because you've applied the rotation to your whole object including the tyres. Unfortunately it's not going to be easy to reset that without a lot of guesswork. Once you manage that you'll also need to apply the mirror modifier to the tyres, seperate them into different objects and then set the origin for each tyre if you want to steer your model as well as just rotate the wheels.

Answer (score 1):

See if I select the Local orientation, you need to align the origin of your tyre back to its faces orientation:

[image]

In *Edit* mode, select an face ring and create a custom orientation based on this selection:

[image]

In the *Options* panel, activate the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

Go into the *Object panel > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation* in order to align the origin to the custom orientation:

[image]

[image]

Disable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option, switch back to *Global* orientation:

[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset the object rotation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That really helped me a lot